# SQL Impala Case When Minimums

Tags: sql, impala

[image: see data here]

I am looking to make a query with a case when and a minimum aggregate function but keep getting errors.

I am trying to find the min(*EBP*) where *EBP* >= *Fare* else min of all *EBP* (grouping by date)

For example 1-Jan *EBP* is 12, the minimum *EBP* that is greater than or equal to *Fare* and
2-Jan no *EBP* are greater than fare so *EBP* is 5

This seems simple enough but I either get errors or the wrong minimums. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation like this:

```
select date,
       coalesce(min(case when epb > fare then epb end), min(epb)) as epb,
       fare
from t
group by date, fare
```